# Complexity of a Borel linear subspace of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, descriptive-set-theory

This question is inspired by the MO question [Image of $L^1$ under the Fourier transform](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126923/image-of-l1-under-the-fourier-transform?rq=1), but I think it might be much easier so I am posting it here instead.

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a separable Banach space, and $E$ a linear subspace.

> 1. Suppose $E$ is Borel.  What can be the complexity of $E$, in the sense of the [Borel hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy)?  (For example, as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309671/can-a-proper-vector-subspace-of-a-banach-space-be-a-countable-intersection-of-de?rq=1), it cannot be properly $G_\delta$.)  Can $E$ have arbitrarily high Borel rank?

Let us say $E$ is **Banachable** if there is another norm $\|\cdot\|'$ on $E$, stronger than $\|\cdot\|$, under which $E$ is separable Banach.  Or equivalently, $E$ is Banachable iff there exists a separable Banach space $Y$ and a continuous injective linear map $T : Y \to X$ whose image is $E$.  It is clear that every Banachable subspace is Borel.

> 2. <s>Is every Borel subspace Banachable?</s> Trivially no; consider any $E$ which is of countably infinite Hamel dimension.
>
> 3. If not, what can be the complexity of a Banachable subspace?
>
> 4. Do these answers change if I replace "Banach" by "Hilbert" throughout?

One could also ask the analogous questions for Polish groups.

Comment: I suspect at least some of what you're asking about can be found in my answer to [Does there exist a linearly independent and dense subset?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60057/does-there-exist-a-linearly-independent-and-dense-subset) and/or the references given in my answer.

Comment: @dave: Indeed, it seems to resolve #1 completely. I will have a look at the references you cite. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know a reference for "every Banachable subspace is Borel"? I was trying to find one to answer [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2179043) where the result is quoted with a cryptic remark "by Kuratowski's theorem". Could not find anything connecting Kuratowski to this statement. But found [this article](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07010918) which claims that separable Borel subspaces are precisely continuous images of separable Banach spaces, which seems to answer your question 2. No reference given, though...

Comment: @NormalHuman: In general, whenever $X,Y$ are standard Borel spaces and $T : Y \to X$ is Borel and injective, then the image $E = T(Y)$ is Borel in $X$.  This is Theorem 15.1 in Kechris *Classical Descriptive Set Theory*.  So it holds in particular when $X,Y$ are separable Banach spaces and $T$ is continuous.