# What does "Kuratowski's theorem" refer to in the context of dense linear subspaces being Borel?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

Kuratowski was a busy man who showed many results in topology and functional analysis, so when a writer says that some result follows from ''Kuratowski's theorem", it could apply to many different ones.

I am currently studying ["Stochastic Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction", by Wei Liu and Michael Röckner](https://books.google.nl/books?id=2QS0CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=In+this+chapter+we+will+present+one+specific+method+to+solve+stochastic+differential+equations+in+infinite+dimensional+spaces,+known+as+the+variational+approach.+The+main+criterion+for+this+approach+to+work+is+that+the+coefficients+satisfy+certain+monotonicity+assumptions.+As+the+main+references+for+Sect.+4.2+wemention+%5B54,+69%5D,+but+one+should+also+check+the+references+therein,+in+particular+the+pioneering+work+%5B65%5D.+Section+4.1+is+devoted+to+formulating+the+necessary+conditions+and+a+number+of+key+applications.+In+the+last+section+we+study+the+Markov&source=bl&ots=TCwlGcGZnH&sig=brdl7moKzGJxWoPUxBJ387qE1ys&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdjuKIrcnSAhXB2xoKHdUHBqMQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=In%20this%20chapter%20we%20will%20present%20one%20specific%20method%20to%20solve%20stochastic%20differential%20equations%20in%20infinite%20dimensional%20spaces%2C%20known%20as%20the%20variational%20approach.%20The%20main%20criterion%20for%20this%20approach%20to%20work%20is%20that%20the%20coefficients%20satisfy%20certain%20monotonicity%20assumptions.%20As%20the%20main%20references%20for%20Sect.%204.2%20wemention%20%5B54%2C%2069%5D%2C%20but%20one%20should%20also%20check%20the%20references%20therein%2C%20in%20particular%20the%20pioneering%20work%20%5B65%5D.%20Section%204.1%20is%20devoted%20to%20formulating%20the%20necessary%20conditions%20and%20a%20number%20of%20key%20applications.%20In%20the%20last%20section%20we%20study%20the%20Markov&f=false) and in Chapter 4, they introduce the Gelfand triple $\left(V,H,V^*\right)$ and sketch the situation where they work in.

For this Gelfand triple (or evolution triple), we have a reflexive Banach space $\left(V,\|\cdot\|_{V}\right)$ and a Hilbert space $\left(H,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{H}\right)$, such that $V \subset H$ and $V$ can be continuously and densely embedded in $H$. It also follows that $H^*$ can be densely embedded into $V^*$, by restricting the functionals on $H$ to $V$ (call this (isomorphic!) map $\rho$). As the Hilbert space $H$ and its dual are isomorphic by the Riesz representation map $\Phi$, we can identify $H$ and its image under the map $\rho\circ\Phi$; we will write $\bar{H}$ for $\rho(\Phi(H))$.

Then, they claim that by *Kuratowski's theorem*, we know that 
$$
V \in \mathcal{B}(H) \quad \text{ and } \quad \bar{H}\in\mathcal{B}\left(V^*\right)
$$
but I don't know which theorem they refer to and that is my question. I've scoured the internet to find what they mean, but my attempts have not yet been fruitful, so I was wondering if any of you could help me out.

Comment: I might be inclined not so much to look for a theorem by Kuratowski, but for a book on PDEs written by authors who had more respect for their readers' time.

Comment: @NormalHuman: Excuse me, I forgot to include that $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-field of $H$.

Comment: @NormalHuman And I completely forgot to answer your question: the way this is set up is to show the existence of solutions to stochastic differential equations. They first assume the solutions are $V^*$-valued, but that they really are $\bar{H}$-valued, so can be translated back to being $H$-valued. That is essentially what it comes down to. 

If you think: what is this bloke rattling about, then I agree that my comment might not be particularly helpful.

Comment: @JohnHughes Any recommendations?

Comment: None at all -- this is completely outside my area of expertise. But it's a general rule: avoid authors who don't take *your* time seriously.

Comment: @JohnHughes  Ah, that's a bummer. Thanks for your quick response anyway!

Comment: @johnhughes is certainly right about generally avoiding texts which send you on snipe hunts. With that said, it's slim pickings for stochastic PDE texts, but I prefer Prevot and Roeckner as an elementary text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the authors refer to the following theorem:

> **Theorem**. Suppose $X, Y$ are Polish spaces and $f : X \to Y$ is continuous. If $A \subset X$ is Borel and $f_{|A}$ is injective, then $f(A)$ is Borel.

It is a theorem of Lusin and Souslin, as stated in [Classical Descriptive Set Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=WR3SBwAAQBAJ) by Alexander Kechris, Theorem 15.1 on page 89. Sometimes it's attributed to Lusin alone. I haven't been able to connect Kuratowski to this result.

Every separable Banach space is a [Polish space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_space), and the embeddings $V\subset H$ and $H^*\subset V^*$ are continuous injective maps. So one needs to assume that $H$ (equivalently, $V$) is separable, which I believe is a standard assumption when considering Gelfand triples.

Comment: Great find! Did it take long?

(I indeed forgot to mention that these spaces were assumed to be separable.)

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary of the previous answer, Kuratowski proved a similar result to Souslin's for Borel measurable mappings (not only continuous mappings) in page 489 of his book "Topology: Volume I".